# Laravel's firstOrNew combined with a join?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table titled `user_buys`, that looks something like:

```
id | item_id | value | date
```

When I want to create a new entry, I check that there is already an entry for the same `item_id` on the same `date`, like this:

```
$entry = UserBuy::firstOrNew(array('item_id' => $item_id,'user_id' => Auth::id(), 'date' => $date));
    $entry->value = $value;
    $entry->save();
```

So if an entry exists, just update the `value` column. But, there's a catch. There is another table titled `user_sales`, that looks like:

```
id | buy_id | sale_price
```

where `buy_id` is the `id` from `user_buys`. If the `firstOrNew` function finds an existing entry for the `item_id/date` combination, it should also check that it doesn't exist in the `user_sales` table. So basically I need a `leftJoin` to check whether the item that was bought has already been sold. In this case, I need to create a new entry in `user_buys` and not update the existing one.

I could write more convoluted code to do this with about 3 separate queries, but I was wondering if there is a way to make this additional check using the `firstOrNew` approach.

Comment: You just need to do the same thing to the UserSales model after UserBuy, nothing wrong. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you are :) I don't want to create a new record in UserSale, I just need to check whether a record exists for the buy_id in question and, if so, create a new entry in UserBuy instead of updating it.